# How to Query Session ID for RDP Shadowing On Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

When trying to use RDP shadowing, one of the necessary parameters is the session ID that you want to actually shadow:

`mstsc shadow:$sessionID /v:$computerName`

Every article I've read online suggests using `qwinsta` or `query` to obtain the currently active session IDs from the client you want to connect to using RDP. However, these utilities are only available on Windows Server edition, not Windows 10 Home. Attempting to use them on Windows 10 Home simply returns a "`command` not recognized as internal or external command" error.

Is there any way to obtain the session ID of a client from the server you want to connect with on Windows 10 Home? I've tried just brute forcing the ID, and this has worked for me at points--but it seems to constantly change.

Thanks!